# Why is the over sampler slowing down my signal?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, adc, dac

at it again.

This time I am playing around with oversampler in the [STM32L432KC](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00151940-stm32l41xxx42xxx43xxx44xxx45xxx46xxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf). Page 425.

Currently sampling at 44.410kHz.
Making my Nyquist rate ~22205Hz.

Everytime I enable the oversampler to have a ratio of 2x and no bit shifting, it makes everything slower by that ratio. I thought the over sampler would increase the speed by the ratio that its told to do.

For example: (What I thought would happen)

- Sampling @ 44.410kHz using the oversampler at 2x ratio my new sampling rate would be 88.82kHz.

Whats happening:

- My signal becomes distorted and the interrupts I had in place for half complete and full complete becomes longer.
- Half complete would send an interrupt at 90us now with the 2x ratio its around ~ 180us.

Summary

- Trying to enable the over sampler at 2x ratio with no bit shifting
- Makes my output signal distorted
- It doubles the problem operation time from 90us -> 180us

Pictures:
[image: Oversampler: Disabled]
Over Sampler: Disabled
[image]
Over Sampler: Enabled

Code:

```
#include "main.h"
#include <stdint.h>
void init_Interrupt(void);
void init_Clock(void);
void init_Interrupt(void);
void init_DAC(void);
void init_ADC(void);
void init_GPIO_Test(void);
void init_Debug(void);
void print_ADC(short);
void init_Timer(void);
char buffer[20] = "ADC Value:     \n\r";
typedef struct PLL{
    uint8_t PLLN;
    uint8_t PLLR;
    uint8_t PLLM;
    uint8_t PLLSAI1N;
    uint8_t PLLSAI1R;
} PLL;
PLL find_PLL(uint32_t, uint32_t);
PLL CFGR;
uint8_t escape = 0;
uint8_t half_transfer_complete = 0;
uint8_t transfer_complete = 0;
uint32_t PLLN_MAX = 86;
uint32_t PLLSAI1N_MAX = 86;
uint32_t PLLR_MAX = 8;
uint32_t PLLSAI1R_MAX = 8;
uint32_t PLLM_MAX = 8;
uint32_t CPU_Speed = 80000000;
uint32_t ADC_Speed = 29000000;
uint16_t ADC_Value[8]; //  Hold 8 Samples
void DMA2_Channel3_IRQHandler(void){
    if (((DMA2->ISR) & (DMA_ISR_HTIF3)) != 0){
        half_transfer_complete = 1;
        DMA2->IFCR |= DMA_IFCR_CHTIF3;
    } else if (((DMA2->ISR) & (DMA_ISR_TCIF3)) != 0){
        transfer_complete = 1;
        DMA2->IFCR |= DMA_IFCR_CTCIF3;
    }
}
int main(void) {
  init_Clock();
  //init_Debug();
  init_ADC();
  init_DAC();
  init_GPIO_Test();
  init_Interrupt();
  init_Timer();
    while (1) {
            if (half_transfer_complete == 1){
                TIM6 ->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
                GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS0;

                half_transfer_complete = 0;
            }
            if (transfer_complete == 1){
                GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR0;
                transfer_complete = 0;
            }
    };
}
PLL find_PLL(uint32_t CPU_Speed, uint32_t ADC_Speed) {
    PLL settings;
     for (int PLLN = 8; PLLN <= PLLN_MAX; PLLN ++){
        if (escape == 1){
            break;
        }
         for (int PLLM = 1; PLLM <= PLLM_MAX; PLLM ++){
             if (escape == 1){
                 break;
             }
            for (int PLLR = 2; PLLR <= PLLR_MAX ; PLLR +=2){
                if ((((4000000/PLLM) * PLLN) >= 64000000) & (((4000000/PLLM) * PLLN) <= 344000000)){
                    if (((4000000/PLLM) >= 4000000) & ((4000000/PLLM) <= 16000000)) {
                        if (((((4000000/PLLM)*PLLN)/PLLR) >= 8000000) & ((((4000000/PLLM)*PLLN)/PLLR) <= 80000000)){
                           uint32_t PLL_CALC = (((4000000/PLLM)*PLLN)/PLLR);
                            if (PLL_CALC == CPU_Speed){
                              settings.PLLM = PLLM;
                              settings.PLLR = PLLR;
                              settings.PLLN = PLLN;
                              escape = 1;
                              break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
        escape = 0;
        for (int PLLSAI1N = 8; PLLSAI1N <= PLLSAI1N_MAX; PLLSAI1N ++){
            if (escape == 1){
                 break;
        }
            for (int PLLSAI1R = 2; PLLSAI1R <= PLLSAI1R_MAX; PLLSAI1R += 2){
                if ((((4000000/settings.PLLM) * PLLSAI1N) >= 64000000) & (((4000000/settings.PLLM) * PLLSAI1N) <= 344000000)){
                   if (((((4000000/settings.PLLM)*PLLSAI1N)/PLLSAI1R) >= 8000000) & ((((4000000/settings.PLLM)*PLLSAI1N)/PLLSAI1R) <= 80000000)){
                       uint32_t PLLSAI1_CALC = (((4000000/settings.PLLM)*PLLSAI1N)/PLLSAI1R);
                       if (PLLSAI1_CALC == ADC_Speed){
                        settings.PLLSAI1R = PLLSAI1R;
                        settings.PLLSAI1N = PLLSAI1N;
                        escape = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                   }
                }
            }
          }
                return settings;
        }
void init_ADC(){
        //Pin - A6
        RCC   -> AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN | RCC_AHB2ENR_ADCEN;
        RCC   -> AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA2EN;
        RCC   -> CCIPR   |= RCC_CCIPR_ADCSEL_1;
        GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE7;
        GPIOA -> MODER |=  GPIO_MODER_MODE7_Analog; //PIN A6
        // |------------------- ADC VALUE ----------------------|
        // 16-bit @ Sampling ~44.410kHZ
        //Holding 8 samples at a time
        // 16-bit = 2 byte * 8 =  16 bytes
        DMA2_Channel3 -> CCR |= (DMA_CCR_PSIZE_16_Bit) |
                              (DMA_CCR_MSIZE_16_Bit)   |
                              (DMA_CCR_MINC)           |
                              (DMA_CCR_CIRC)           |
                              (DMA_CCR_TCIE)           |
                              (DMA_CCR_HTIE)           |
                              (DMA_CCR_PL_Very_High);
        DMA2_CSELR    -> CSELR &= ~DMA_CSELR_C3S;
        DMA2_Channel3 -> CNDTR |= 0x08;
        DMA2_Channel3 -> CMAR = (uint32_t)ADC_Value; //Memory Address
        DMA2_Channel3 -> CPAR = (uint32_t)&ADC1->DR; //Peripheral Addres
        DMA2_Channel3 -> CCR |= DMA_CCR_EN;
        ADC1 -> CR &= ~ADC_CR_DEEPPWD;
        ADC1 -> CR |= ADC_CR_ADVREGEN;
        ADC1 -> CR &= ~ADC_CR_ADCALDIF;
        ADC1 -> CR |= ADC_CR_ADCAL;
        while((ADC1->CR & ADC_CR_ADCAL) != 0) //Wait for Calibration to be done
        ;
        ADC1 -> CFGR  |= ADC_CFGR_CONT | ADC_CFGR_DMACFG | ADC_CFGR_DMAEN;
        ADC1 -> CFGR  &= ~ADC_CFGR_ALIGN_RIGHT | ADC_CFGR_RES_12_Bit;
        ADC1 -> SMPR2 |= ADC_SMPR2_SMP12_640_ADC_CYCLES;
        ADC1 -> SQR1  |= ADC_SQR1_SQ1_12;
        ADC1 ->CFGR2  |= ADC_CFGR2_ROVSE;
        ADC1 -> ISR |= ADC_ISR_ADRDY;
        ADC1 -> CR  |= ADC_CR_ADEN; //Enable: ADC

        while((ADC1->ISR & ADC_ISR_ADRDY) == 0) //Wait for the ADC to be ready
        ;
        ADC1 -> ISR  |= ADC_ISR_ADRDY; //Clear the ARDYFlAG
        ADC1 -> CR   |= ADC_CR_ADSTART; //Start the ADC

}
void init_Clock() {
    CFGR = find_PLL(CPU_Speed, ADC_Speed);
        // |----------------------------------- WAIT STATE: 0 -----------------------------------|
        if (CPU_Speed <= 16000000) {
            FLASH -> ACR &= ~FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_Msk;
            FLASH -> ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_0WS;
            if ((FLASH -> ACR & FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_0WS) != FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_0WS){
                //ERROR: System didn't change wait states properly
            } else{
                //Success
            }
        // |----------------------------------- WAIT STATE: 1 -----------------------------------|
        } else if (CPU_Speed <= 32000000){
            FLASH -> ACR &= ~FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_Msk;
            FLASH -> ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_1WS;
            if ((FLASH -> ACR & FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_1WS) != FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_1WS){
                //ERROR: System didn't change wait states properly
            } else{
                //Success
        }

        // |----------------------------------- WAIT STATE: 2 -----------------------------------|
        } else if (CPU_Speed <= 48000000){
            FLASH -> ACR &= ~FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_Msk;
            FLASH -> ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_2WS;
            if ((FLASH -> ACR & FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_2WS) != FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_2WS){
                //ERROR: System didn't change wait states properly
            } else{
                //Success
            }

        // |----------------------------------- WAIT STATE: 3 -----------------------------------|
        } else if (CPU_Speed <= 64000000){
            FLASH -> ACR &= ~FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_Msk;
            FLASH -> ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_3WS;
            if ((FLASH -> ACR & FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_3WS) != FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_3WS){
                //ERROR: System didn't change wait states properly
            } else{
                //Success
            }

        // |----------------------------------- WAIT STATE: 4 -----------------------------------|
        } else if (CPU_Speed <= 80000000){
            FLASH -> ACR &= ~FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_Msk;
            FLASH -> ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_4WS;
            if ((FLASH -> ACR & FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_4WS) != FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_4WS){
                //ERROR: System didn't change wait states properly
            } else{
                //Success
            }
        } else{
            //Error: Clock Speed too high
        }
        RCC -> CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;
        PWR -> CR1  &= ~PWR_CR1_VOS_Msk;
        PWR -> CR1  |= PWR_CR1_VOS_0;
        RCC -> CR   |= RCC_CR_MSIRGSEL | RCC_CR_MSIRANGE_6;
        // |----------------------------------- PLLCFGR: R -----------------------------------|
        if (CFGR.PLLR == 2){
            RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLR_Msk;
            RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLR_2;
        } else if (CFGR.PLLR == 4){
            RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLR_Msk;
            RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLR_4;
        } else if (CFGR.PLLR == 6){
            RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLR_Msk;
            RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLR_6;
        } else if (CFGR.PLLR == 8){
            RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLR_Msk;
            RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLR_8;
        }
        // |----------------------------------- PLLCFGR: M -----------------------------------|
        if (CFGR.PLLM == 1){
            RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Msk;
        } else {
            RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Msk;
            RCC -> PLLCFGR |= (CFGR.PLLM-1) << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Pos;
        }
        // |----------------------------------- PLLCFGR: N -----------------------------------|
        RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~(RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Msk);
        RCC -> PLLCFGR |= ((CFGR.PLLN) << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos) | (RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLREN) | (RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_MSI);
        // |----------------------------------- PLLSAI1CFGR: R -----------------------------------|
        if (CFGR.PLLSAI1R == 2){
            RCC -> PLLSAI1CFGR &= ~RCC_PLLSAI1CFGR_PLLSAI1R_Msk;
            RCC -> PLLSAI1CFGR |= RCC_PLLSAI1CFGR_PLLSAI1R_2;
        } else if (CFGR.PLLSAI1R == 4){
            RCC -> PLLSAI1CFGR &= ~RCC_PLLSAI1CFGR_PLLSAI1R_Msk;
            RCC -> PLLSAI1CFGR |= RCC_PLLSAI1CFGR_PLLSAI1R_4;
        } else if (CFGR.PLLSAI1R == 6){
            RCC -> PLLSAI1CFGR &= ~RCC_PLLSAI1CFGR_PLLSAI1R_Msk;
            RCC -> PLLSAI1CFGR |= RCC_PLLSAI1CFGR_PLLSAI1R_6;
        } else if (CFGR.PLLSAI1R == 8){
            RCC->PLLSAI1CFGR &= ~RCC_PLLSAI1CFGR_PLLSAI1R_Msk;
            RCC->PLLSAI1CFGR |= RCC_PLLSAI1CFGR_PLLSAI1R_8;
        }
        // |----------------------------------- PLLSAI1CFGR: N -----------------------------------|
        RCC -> PLLSAI1CFGR &= ~(RCC_PLLSAI1CFGR_PLLSAI1N_Msk);
        RCC -> PLLSAI1CFGR |= RCC_PLLSAI1CFGR_PLLSAI1REN | (CFGR.PLLSAI1N << RCC_PLLSAI1CFGR_PLLSAI1N_Pos);
        RCC -> CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;
        while ((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY) == 0)
        ;
        RCC -> CR |= RCC_CR_PLLSAI1ON;
        while ((RCC -> CR & RCC_CR_PLLSAI1RDY) == 0)
        ;
        if ((RCC -> CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL ) {
            //Error: Clock Didn't switch
        }
}
void init_DAC(){
    //Pin A3
    RCC   -> APB1ENR1 |= RCC_APB1ENR1_DAC1EN;
    RCC   -> AHB2ENR  |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN;
    GPIOA -> MODER    &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE4;
    GPIOA -> MODER    |= GPIO_MODER_MODE4_Analog;
    DAC1  -> CR       |= DAC_CR_EN1;
}
void init_Interrupt(){
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Channel3_IRQn);
    NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Channel3_IRQn,0);
}
void init_GPIO_Test(){
    RCC   -> AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN;
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE0;
    GPIOA -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE0_Gen_Purpose;
}
void print_ADC(short adcValue){
    short counter = 0;
    while (adcValue > 0){
        buffer[14-counter] = (adcValue % 10) + '0';
        adcValue = adcValue / 10;
        counter++;
    }
    if (counter == 0){
        buffer[14] = adcValue + '0';
        buffer[13] = ' ';
        buffer[12] = ' ';
        buffer[11] = ' ';
    } else if (counter == 1){
         buffer[13] = ' ';
         buffer[12] = ' ';
         buffer[11] = ' ';
    } else if (counter == 2){
         buffer[12] = ' ';
         buffer[11] = ' ';
    } else if (counter == 3){
         buffer[11] = ' ';
  }
    counter = 0;
}
void init_Debug(){
    RCC -> APB1ENR1 |= RCC_APB1ENR1_USART2EN;
    RCC -> AHB1ENR  |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN;
    RCC -> AHB2ENR  |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN;
    RCC -> CCIPR    |= RCC_CCIPR_USART2SEL_System_Clock;
    GPIOA -> MODER  &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE2;
    GPIOA -> MODER  |= GPIO_MODER_MODE2_Alt_Function;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL2_USART2;
    DMA1_Channel7 -> CCR  |= DMA_CCR_PL_High     |
                             DMA_CCR_MSIZE_8_Bit |
                             DMA_CCR_PSIZE_8_Bit |
                             DMA_CCR_MINC        |
                             DMA_CCR_CIRC        |
                             DMA_CCR_DIR;
    DMA1_CSELR    -> CSELR |= DMA_CSELR_C7S_USART2;
    DMA1_Channel7 -> CNDTR  = 0x14; // 20
    DMA1_Channel7 -> CMAR   = (uint32_t)buffer;
    DMA1_Channel7 -> CPAR   = (uint32_t)&USART2 -> TDR;
    DMA1_Channel7 -> CCR  |= DMA_CCR_EN;
    USART2 -> CR1 &= ~USART_CR1_M1 | ~USART_CR1_OVER16;
    USART2 -> CR1 |= USART_CR1_TE;
    USART2 -> CR3 |= USART_CR3_DMAT;
    USART2 -> BRR  = 0x208D;
    USART2 -> CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;
}
void init_Timer(){
    RCC -> AHB1ENR  |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN;
    RCC -> APB1ENR1 |= RCC_APB1ENR1_TIM6EN;
    DMA1_Channel3 -> CCR |= DMA_CCR_PL_Very_High |
                            DMA_CCR_MSIZE_16_Bit |
                            DMA_CCR_PSIZE_16_Bit |
                            DMA_CCR_MINC         |
                            DMA_CCR_CIRC         |
                            DMA_CCR_DIR;
    DMA1_Channel3 -> CNDTR  = 0x08;
    DMA1_Channel3 -> CPAR   = (uint32_t)&DAC1->DHR12R1;
    DMA1_Channel3 -> CMAR   = (uint32_t)ADC_Value;
    DMA1_CSELR    -> CSELR |= DMA_CSELR_C3S_TIM_6_UP;
    DMA1_Channel3 -> CCR   |= DMA_CCR_EN;
    TIM6 -> DIER |= TIM_DIER_UDE;
    TIM6 -> ARR   = 0x384;
    TIM6 -> PSC   = 0x0;
}
```

Comment: Suggested reading: the fine reference manual, page 425, section 16.4.30 "Oversampler". It does not do what you think it does. Enabling the oversampler does not change the 'raw' underlying sample rate, but it does effectively reduce it by the oversampling factor, because it's taking multiple samples and adding them together into one oversampled sample for you.

Comment: I see, I dont see it anywhere in the doc that it will simply reduce it by the oversampling factor. Is that what a over sampler suppose to do? Or is this STM32 way of doing it

Comment: Nothing in the manual says that the oversampler is going to go through and reconfigure the clocks for you, so safe assumption is that it isn't going to do that.

Comment: It literally says in the manual you link: *There are no changes for conversion timings in oversampled mode: the sample time is
maintained equal during the whole oversampling sequence.*

Comment: Ahh, thank you guys. Just saw the literature